# ruby on rails ubuntu 13.10 installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to install ruby on rails on ubuntu 13.10.

I'm following these steps: http://www.thekunit.com/installing-ruby-rails-ubuntu/

After I type the lines for Installing RVM it says: Abort.

Are the steps from this link correct (are they exactly what I should type or is there something more that is considered to be very obvious and is not written here?), why does this abort happen and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use rvm doc to install rvm and ruby. It is sufficient.

http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Thanks, I think I did it. Do you maybe know how to install mySql gem too?

Comment: Gem install mysql2. However if that fail while installing native libs, just check the log file mentioned in that error msg. Any lib that it would have fail to install would be marked as 'no.....' . search for the library on google and install it manualy and then retry :gem install mysql2'

Comment: Sorry but how exactly can I check mkmf.log file?